# Canon TS-E Aperture Question

Tags: canon

I have been considering a 24mm TS-E lens but one question that may help me decide to pull the trigger is the question of aperture.  I frequently shoot at mid to high aperture settings in order to get more depth of field in my low-light landscape photography, resulting in frequently shooting at less than desirable shutter speeds.  I want to avoid ISO higher than 200 or shutter speeds below 1/30 but still get a deep depth of field.

My question, in general, is this: does the the tilt and shift provisions give me full depth of field at modest apertures?   Putting aside the geometric correction that a 24mm TS-E lens will give me, would I be better off with that lens than with a 24mm 1.4 II EF L lens if I want to shoot at 1/30 or faster and an aperture of say f/3.5?

Comment: Why aren't you considering a tripod to remove the slow shutter speed requirement? And can you clarify "full depth of field" (what constitutes full? hyperfocal?) and "mid-to-high" aperture (is high a high f-number or a large aperture?) and why you'd even care about larger apertures like f/3.5 and f/1.4 for _landscape_ shooting?

Comment: Most of my photography IS on tripods; I happen to travel to tropical destinations a lot, and most of the pictures I take have water, wind, foliage and some I end up with some blurry elements when shot slower than 1/30 of seconds.  I shoot quite often at much smaller apertures, but invariably in pre-sunrise or post sunset shots, which I find spectacular effects in, moving water and foliage movement force me down to wide open, therefore my querry about the 24mm 1.4 L and TS-E lens with the hope that for those tougher shots I get better results.

Answer (score 1):

Shift doesn't affect depth of field (DoF) at all.

Tilt doesn't really change the 'thickness' of the DoF, it just tilts it.

**Depending on the composition of the scene and which way you tilt the lens you can create an image that *appears* to have either much more or much less DoF than the same aperture when used with a conventional lens where the field of focus is more or less parallel to the camera's sensor.**

For example, if your camera is about 5 feet above the ground and pointed level to the horizon then the ground at the bottom of the frame is much closer to you than the ground near the horizon. By tilting the lens downward towards the ground it will make the DoF look deeper because the plane of focus will be tilted closer to the plane of the ground. By tilting the lens upward away from the ground it will make the DoF look narrower because the plane of focus will be tilted away from the plane of the ground.

This is more critical with lenses such as the 45mm and 90mm TS-E lenses. At 24mm you're already getting significant DoF at narrower apertures and using the tilt to place more of the scene closer to the same angle as the plane of focus will increase that *apparent* DoF even more.

Answer (score 0):

The shift function does not affect the depth-of-field, only the geometric distortion issues.

The tilt function, depending on the degree of tilt, allows you to achieve a little to a lot **MORE** depth-of-field at any given aperture than a '*non-tiltable*' lens (like e.g., 24mm 1.4 II EF L lens) at that same aperture.

However, having said that, with such a generous depth-of-field already, especially in your chosen low-light photography manner, it is difficult to ascertain the effects of the tilting. Believe me, I often struggle to see the exact plane of perfect focus when using the tilit function on my TS-E 24mm, even in reasonably bright light and at f3.5, mainly because the 24 already has impressive depth-of-field .

Possibly the only benefit of the 24mm f1.4 II, having a wider max aperture then the TS-E, will be for the exposure benefits, enabling shorter shutter speeds and / or lower ISO.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  My specific complaint arises from wanting to shoot post-sunset and pre-sunrise and moon-lit scenes where there is moving water and foliage.  Based on your feedback, I am guessing the TS-E will be hard to work with in such low light environment and that perhaps the 24mm 1.4 may be a better option.  In fact on the 16-35mm I now use, I frequently have to use live view and manually focus on any available light source, and I imagine the TS-E will be a challenge then.  Would you agree in that case the 1.4L would be better for me?

Comment: @SamDimani  If you compose and focus at maximum aperture, the 1.4L is 'better' in that regard.  But if you want to gain additional apparent [so called] 'depth-of-field' at a particular taking aperture , then the tilt function of TS-E will be advantageous. Michael Clark's answer explains the principle more technically correctly.

Comment: I agree, his and your explanation made it clear that TS-E will give me a more apparent "deeper" DOF at a given aperture than with the EF 1.4 II; and that is appealing to me; but given that about 30 percent of my shoots are in very low light situations, I have to weigh in the fact that I can go as low as 1.4 and shoot at speeds three times faster.  I am now thinking I may need both.  My wife got me a 5Ds earlier this year and the temptation to use a 24 mm TS-E with a 50 meg pixel count is piling up on me.  Thank you both.